# Convergence of a series vs. two parameters

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm stuck on finding the convergence of the series:
$$S=\sum_{j=0}^nj^k-\frac{1}{2}n^{\gamma k}$$ for $n\to\infty$ as function of the parameter $\gamma$ and the exponent $k$
with:
$k\in\mathbb{R},k\gt1$ and $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$.
Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: No series here, only a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series converges with whatever $k>1$ and $\gamma<0$, diverges otherwise. This can be seen by noting that
$$
   \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=1}^nj^k=\zeta(-k)=-\frac{B_k}{k+1}.
$$
being $B_k$ the Bernoulli numbers, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone give me some hint?

Hint: Compare each finite sum $\sum\limits_{j=0}^nj^k$ to the Riemann integral of a function and deduce that this is equivalent to a multiple of $n^\ell$, for some well chosen value of $\ell$ depending on $k$. Conclude.